# Installing on new Alder Lake build issues

Tags: bluetooth, intel, usb-installation

I have a new custom build desktop with the following hardware:

Motherboard: Asus PRIME Z690-P WIFI D4
  CPU: Intel Core i5 12600K
  RAM: 32 GB DDR4-3200

I have two old SSDs from previous laptops:

Samsung 960 with dual Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed
  Samsung 970 with Pop!_OS 20.04

And I have a new SSD:

Samsung 980

I am able to boot into any of the old OSs without issue.

When I try to install Kubuntu 20.04 or 21 from USB drive the installation claims to complete correctly, but then when I reboot (after it tells me to take out install media) I get various versions of the following errors (also I'm choosing encrypted LVM when I install) after I decrypt:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-14: device not accepting address 17, error -71
usb 1-14: device not accepting address 18, error -71
usb usb1-port14: unable to enumerate USB device
hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: unable to bind codec
```

Then it hangs. I've tried installing with the other SSDs removed as well and had the same problem.

[image: error screen]

Oddly when I then reinstall the other SSDs and try to reboot into Pop!_OS I get similar errors.

[image]

I can get it to boot correctly again by removing the 980 SSD and doing a combination of restarting and switching back and forth between booting into Windows 10 and then Pop!_OS (I'm not exactly sure what is getting the job done here.)

I'm going to try with just vanilla Ubuntu 21 and see if that makes any difference. I'm thinking part of the issue is that this new hardware is only supported in the newest kernel.

Let me know whatever additional information I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this finally by putting the newest Linux kernel on a thumb drive - booting into Ubuntu safe mode -updating to newest kernel.  Still some issues with supporting the Intel integrated GPU but I got an external AMD so i'm all set.